# How do I access props for a particular page in getInitialprops for a functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Say I have a page called `dashboard.js` which is a functional component and I am wrapping it in an "HOC" which injects some props to it.

`export default withAuthentication(Dashboard);`

How do I access the props injected by the "HOC" in `Dashboard.getInitialProps` function?

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the Component's props in Next.js' static `getInitialProps` method, because it runs before the Component is mounted and as its name says you can create the initial props for the Component.